# How to securely pass a password to a PM2 nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, bash, security, pm2

Right now I'm passing sensitive data to PM2 using env variables. This way the `PASSWORD` is available to all node instances via `process.env.PASSWORD`.

```
get_password () {
  read -s -p "Enter password:"
  if [[ -z $REPLY ]]; then
    get_password
  else
    echo $REPLY
  fi
}

PASSWORD=$(get_password) || exit 1

eval "PASSWORD=$PASSWORD pm2 start ecosystem.config.js"
```

I have concerns regarding the security of this, because I've just learned [here(point 2)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/069) that:

> The initial environment of a process is generally visible in ps

It made me rethink my approach.

Instead I could use `readline` NPM package to ask user for password, but it's not a great solution, because if I, say, have 8 running instances, then I need to manually enter the password 8 times.

What would you advice?

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need the `eval` (unless you plan to execute code stored in `$PASSWORD`).

Comment: @Socowi, oh, right! Thank you, good sir!